# Backend "sox_io" is not one of available backends: ['soundfile']

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I have try to study deep learning in colab with local runtime but after a few step I got the error
notice: I use windows 10

link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14-smojGNfo-Gr_voM9AfcMiuV9YvXWU1?hl=en

I've got error from this line:

```
show_random_elements(common_voice_train.remove_columns(["path"]), num_examples=20)
```

the error:

```
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\datasets\features\audio.py:175, in Audio._decode_mp3(self, path_or_file)
        174     import torchaudio.transforms as T
    --> 175     torchaudio.set_audio_backend("sox_io")
        176 except RuntimeError as err:      
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\backend\utils.py:43, in set_audio_backend(backend)
         42 if backend is not None and backend not in list_audio_backends():
    ---> 43     raise RuntimeError(
         44         f'Backend "{backend}" is not one of '
         45         f'available backends: {list_audio_backends()}.')
         47 if backend is None:

To support decoding 'mp3' audio files, please install 'sox'.
```

it seem I need to install sox but I already installed it. the windows cant use sox to decode so I also install soundfile but the problem still be there